# How to get a median odds ratio from a logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, database

I am running the regression:

```
model <- glm(Outcome ~ X1 + X2 + X3, family= quasipoisson, data=df)
```

How do I find the Median Odds Ratio for each variable in this regression?

I see a function `mor(v)`, but what variance would I put in there?

Comment: Why would you apply the median odds ratio for GLM, it is meant for the multilevel models to translate the variance of the random effects into information about the difference between the clusters in these random effects. And you don't have that in your model!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming but statistical analysis. Consider: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is too old to migrate, so it would probably be good to delete and repost on CrossValidated. However, @AhmadMkhatib's answer/comment is appropriate - can you say why you would expect to be able to compute a MOR if you're not doing a multilevel model ... ????